# Jenkins console output gray backgorund after update

Tags: jenkins

We have just updated our jenkins (2.337) and the python console output has gone weird:

[image]

I've searched the jenkins settings (ANSI plugin etc) and I can change the inner colours but the gray background and line breaks remain.  Does anyone know the settings to get it back to the plain old black and white it used to be?

Comment: Probably related to: [JENKINS-64435](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64435) : Running build logs have a different font size than finished build logs / [PR # 6338](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/6338): JENKINS-64435 - Don't show two console boxes when rendering the log file. Maybe comment on those to Devs?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem ... we had an almost Black Background with Black Text

We found that the Extra CSS in the Theme section of the Jenkins Configuration has changed.

After putting it through a code formatter (there are no new lines or whitespace in the field) we had the following for the console-output:

```
.console-output .error-inline{
    color:#f44336
}

.console-output,.console-output *{
    position:relative;
    font-family:Roboto Mono,monospace!important;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#263238;
    color:#e9eded;
    cursor:text
}

.console-output{
    padding:10px 20px
}
```

The "background:#263238;" was giving the Dark Gray background, while the output didn't specify a colour for the text.

Once I updated the '.console-output' CSS to be:

```
.console-output{
    color:#fff!important;
    padding:10px 20px
}
```

it was all resolved.

Looking at your picture, your console output is going to have a lighter gray background while the text block will be a type specified in your CSS, and will have a darker grey background.

Changing both the have the same colour background will resolve your issue. You could use the HTML Code Examiner (F12 in Chrome) to examine the page setup, and track down exactly which items are giving the look you don't like

Answer (score 1):

When you have broken console colors (black font on black screen) after jenkins update,

- Go to Manage Jenkins -> configure system
- scroll to theme
- click add -> extra CSS

put this in the new field:

```
.console-output{
    color:#fff!important;
}
```

You can also add any other CSS to please your eye.

Comment: This must be a plugin, since I don't see this on my configure system page.